# How do I unit test or use assert on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, dataframe, assert

I want to carry out a unit test on my code to be sure the output of the code is correct.

I tried this also from StackOverflow but not working:

```
input = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'rev': [0],
    'price': [0]
})
expected = {
    'data': ['cool']
}

assert_dict_equal(expected, data(input).to_dict(),
                  "oops, there's a bug...")


def temperature(row):
    rev = row['rev']
    price = row['price']
    group = row['group']
    if group == 'error':
        return 'error'
    elif revenue > 2 * price:
        return 'cold'
    elif revenue >= price:
        return 'cool'
    elif revenue < 0.5 * price:
        return 'hot'
    elif revenue < price:
        return 'lukewarm'
    else:
        float('NA')

data['temp'] = sample.apply(temperature, axis=1)

assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 0, "price": 0}, 
                        "group", "rev", "price") == 'cool'

assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 30, "price": 10}, 
                        "group", "rev", "price") == 'cold'

assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 3, "price": 10}, 
                        "group", "rev", "price") == 'hot'
```

Expected result should return without error while the output is giving an error.

TypeError: temperature() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback you are seeing

Comment: Still giving an error after implementing the edit and correction.                            Here is the error: TypeError: temperature() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given.

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicit: you are trying to call `temperature` function with 4 positional arguments in your assertions, while it only takes 1. Replace your assertions with these:

```
assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 0, "price": 0}) == 'cool'
assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 30, "price": 10}) == 'cold'
assert temperature({"group": 'T2_Y2', "rev": 3, "price": 10}) == 'hot'
```

**EDIT** : Based on your comment, change your function to this one:

```
def temperature(row, group_col, rev_col, price_col):
    rev = row[rev_col]
    price = row[price_col]
    group = row[group_col]
    if group == 'error':
        return 'error'
    elif revenue > 2 * price:
        return 'cold'
    elif revenue >= price:
        return 'cool'
    elif revenue < 0.5 * price:
        return 'hot'
    elif revenue < price:
        return 'lukewarm'
    else:
        float('NA')
```

Then keep your asserts as is and it should work

Comment: So how do I reconstruct the assert statement to test the code if I take out other three arguments?

Comment: why do you even want to pass 4 arguments to a function that only takes 1 ? What is the purpose of the other 3 arguments ? In the function definition you don't even use them ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: It's a DataFrame, the other three arguments are columns in the DataFrame. I want to test/check that if I have these values in a row of the DataFrame, it will return the right outcome/temperature.

Comment: See my edited answer. You may want to add some checks like `if group_col in row` to ensure your code doesn't raise `KeyError`